# Can't change total number of randoms

Tags: c, random

My Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{ 
    int z,x,y=0;
    char word[10];

    for(z=0; z <1; z++)
    {
        y=3+rand() % 7; 

        for(x=0; x<y ; x++){
            word[x]= rand()%26+'a';   
        }

        printf("%s\n\n",word);   
    }
}
```

It gives me letters randomly but I couldn't figure out how to make random total subtitutions.

Substitutions must be between 5-10.

For example:

- 1st try: xjhdhfe
- 2nd try: ytfxsszp
- 3rd try: qwety

Comment: "make random their number"?

Comment: You have a broken C implementation. Without `srand()` all runs should give the same result.

Comment: Append a `'\0'` to `word` after the inner `for`-loop. or `memset` the `word` before the inner loop.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking...

Comment: @pmg There is no such guarantee in the C standard. The C standard doesn't require implementation defined behavior to remain consistent between program runs. That's not up to the C standard to decide. I'd like to argue that an implementation that would do that isn't just not broken, it's actually less broken than others.

Comment: @Art: the absence of a call to `srand()`, like @terencehill says, is the same as calling `srand(1)` which has the effect of generating the same sequence of pseudo random numbers in every run of the program.

Comment: @pmg No, it doesn't. The absence of a call to `srand` is the same thing as calling `srand(1)` within the same run of the program. The C standard does not say a single word about what happens if you run the program multiple times. The C standard does not dictate that implementation defined behavior shouldn't change between two runs of a program. It would be a silly thing and impossible to follow. Does updating your system libraries suddenly violate the C standard?

Comment: You're right @Art. Thank you for making me see it right too.

Comment: @pmg It's actually a recent discovery. When OpenBSD decided to get good C language lawyers to show that there is no C standard requirement to have predictable random numbers generators. They later decided to violate the C standard anyway (their `srand` function doesn't do anything), but having `rand` returning actually unpredictable values between program runs is not wrong. This was after analyzing 8000+ programs and only finding two that actually wanted predictable `rand`.

Comment: So ... I can dump my program that produces puzzle #4108716 ... or use a better defined PRNG -- as I did! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep getting the same output every time because you're not seeding the random number generator.  You need to call `srand` to do that.  Otherwise, it always uses a seed of 1.

Also, the value of `y` you're getting will range from 7 - 10 instead of 5 - 10.  To get that, use `y=5+rand() % 6;`.

Finally, `word` isn't big enough to hold a 10 character string.  You need to make the size 11 to make space for the NULL terminator.  Also, after generating the word, you need to add the NULL terminator manually.

After doing the above, your code should look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int z,x,y=0;
    char word[11];

    srand(time(NULL) ^ getpid());
    for(z=0; z <1; z++)
    {
        y=5+rand() % 6;
        for(x=0; x<y ; x++){
            word[x]= rand()%26+'a';
        }
        word[y] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n\n",word);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've not come across that `^ getpid()` in a `srand` call before. Would you mind explaining it's usage / purpose :)?

Comment: `y=5+rand() % 6;` to get range 5 .. 10

Comment: @MPI_What `^` is the bitwise XOR operator.  What it's doing is taking the current time and XORing it with the process ID.  That way, it adds a larger degree of randomness to the seed.

Comment: @WeatherVane  Thanks.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling `rand()` function, you should initiate the seed with something like

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

before the loops.

Then do:

```
y=5+rand() % 6;
```

And it should ramdomize `y` between 5-10 for your second loop.

Greetings.

Comment: `y=5+rand() % 6;` to get range 5 .. 10

Answer (score 0):

Some corrections to your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>                   // required for srand() seed

int main(void)                      // correct function signature
{ 
    int z, x, y=0;
    char word[11];                  // increase array size to allow for \0
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));    // call once at the start of the program
    for(z=0; z<3; z++)
    {
        y = 5 + rand() % 6;         // gives result between 5 and 10
        for(x=0; x<y; x++){
            word[x]= rand() % 26 + 'a';   
        } 
        word[x] = '\0';             // terminate the string
        printf("%s\n",word);   
    }
    return 0;                       // return value from main()
}
```

Program output:

```
rpaelg
pglhhbgvvz
eakcs
```